# Latest Binary builds of FLuentNhibernate + Nhibernate + Linq for NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

do people build there own versions of all this?  or is there a place to get all this prebuilt?

I got the latest FluentNhibernate which has NHibernate but no Linq....  but I don't really want to setup a ruby rake build system etc etc  unless I really really have to!  Prefer to just get all the binaries I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a build:
http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2009/07/nhibernate-210-ga-with-linq-and-fluent.html

Answer (score 0):

I build my own versions, because I don't want to be forced to upgrade all the dependencies of fluent when I just want to upgrade fluentnhibernate.

Installing ruby is downloading and clicking one exe and the rake installer is included in fluent nhibernate repository. This does not require you to read any manual or have any ruby knowledge. It should not take you more than 2 minutes.

Many .net projects use rake instead of nant or msbuild because the syntax of the ruby language is easier to read than xml.

You can download the binaries you want at the buildserver used by [fluent nhibernate](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=8756&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt9)

Comment: "installing ruby is ..."  is everyone having to install ruby, the build machine having to do it.... can't automatically do it when you get an update from the source repository, etc etc.  Which is not huge in the scheme of things,  but it just adds another tool to the toolchain set that every developer needs installed, another thing that needs to be explained, etc.

Comment: Like I said, it's just a preference of syntax of the build script. I am not using it personally, but I do understand that someone else can prefer it over nant or msbuild. Just click the link in the answer if you want to download the binaries.

Comment: I agree with you about "having to install Ruby" is a big disadvantage of using Rake. Another disadvantage is that you have to know Ruby to modify the build script if you need to, and many .net developers do not write or want to write Ruby code. But if you know Ruby, and everyone in your team does, I think Rake is much better than the other build systems. I cannot handle the 2 disadvantages, so I don't use Rake for my own projects. (But I can click on a rake file written by somebody else if I'm forced to do)