# Interoperable Fluent NHibernate + NHibernate + Linq To NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I would like to get all 3 of these libraries working together but have a version problem.

Latest version of `Linq To Hibernate (1.0)` came out on 2009-07-26 and works with `NHibernate 2.1.0` afaik. `Fluent NHibernate`'s oldest release on the other hand is for `NHibernate 2.1.2`.

Google search yielded [this](http://blog.avivasolutions.nl/Attachments/NHibernate.2.1.0.GA.with.linq.and.fluent.zip) zip file of binaries compiled together but it's somewhat outdated (2009-07-19). I'm not sure downloading the latest source code of each project and trying to build them together will work or not, I'd rather not to go that way unless I have to.

I guess the weakest link in this combination is Linq To NHibernate and maybe I should think of leaving it outside if there isn't an active community effort.

**In short**: Does anyone use these libraries together and if so, how did you solve this issue? Do you build it all yourself?

Note:
Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067623/latest-binary-builds-of-fluentnhibernate-nhibernate-linq-for-nhibernate) question but it has been 1 year since it's answered, and the links given in the accepted answer don't work anymore.

Comment: You can rebuild it, but you can also use Nhiberante 3 with the build-in linq provider

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it was bundled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate ver 3 has been released which already has the linq libraries. Download the latest [binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/NHibernate-3.0.0.GA-bin.zip/download).

I don't think Fluent has been updated to use 3 yet so download the latest source for [fluent](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads) and replace the NHibernate assemblies with the new NHibernate version 3 assemblies. You will need to tweak the source ever so slightly so that it compiles. Compile it in release mode and grab the output from the project bin folder.

It has been working fine for us.

**EDIT**

As Kohan pointed out you can download the latest version of Fluent 1.2 with the latest version of NHibernate 3 from the link to Fluent NHibernate I provided earlier.

Comment: There's an updated version of fluent on the download page: http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads

Comment: @Kohan So there is, I posted that link and didn't even notice. Thanks I will have to get it myself.

Comment: Thank you very much Bronumski and Kohan. I didn't know it was bundled in 3.0, I saw the NHContrib Linq page and thought it was inactive for some time.

Comment: @Brunomski you could be forgiven for missing it, it's sort of hidden away there with no indication on the front page. It seems very good though, the linq support is much better all the problems i had in 2.1 are gone.